# Detect ARM NEON availability in the preprocessor?

Tags: gcc, macros, arm, c-preprocessor, neon

According to the [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/BABJFEFG.html), `__ARM_NEON__` is defined when Neon SIMD instructions are available. I'm having trouble getting GCC to provide it.

Neon available on this [BananaPi Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_Pi#Banana_Pi_Pro) dev board running Debian 8.2:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep neon
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt
```

I'm using GCC 4.9:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

Try GCC and `-march=native`:

```
$ g++ -march=native -dM -E - </dev/null | grep -i neon
#define __ARM_NEON_FP 4
```

OK, try what Google uses for Android when building for Neon:

```
$ g++ -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -dM -E - </dev/null | grep -i neon
#define __ARM_NEON_FP 4
```

Maybe a ARMv7-a with a hard float:

```
$ g++ -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -dM -E - </dev/null | grep -i neon
#define __ARM_NEON_FP 4
```

My questions are:

- why am I not seeing `__ARM_NEON__`?
- how do I detect Neon availability in the preprocessor?

And maybe:

- what GCC switches should I use to enable Neon SIMD instructions?

---

Related, on a [LeMaker HiKey](http://www.lenovator.com/product/86.html), which is AARCH64/ARM64 running Linaro with GCC 4.9.2, here's the output from the preprocessor:

```
$ cpp -dM </dev/null | grep -i neon
#define __ARM_NEON 1
```

According to ARM, this board does have Advanced SIMD instructions even though:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Processor   : AArch64 Processor rev 3 (aarch64)
...
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32
```

Comment: `-mfpu=neon`, or maybe `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4`.

Comment: Thanks @EOF. I need to double check the Android build flags to see why its not being used for AOSP toolchains (or maybe it is and my notes are incomplete/broken).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a number of questions hidden in here, I'll try to extract them in turn...

> According to the ARM ARM, `__ARM_NEON__` is defined when Neon SIMD instructions are available. I'm having trouble getting GCC to provide it.

That is compiler documentation for [an old version of] the ARM Compiler rather than the ARM Architceture Reference Manual. A better macro to check for the presence of the Advanced SIMD instructions would be `__ARM_NEON`, which is defined in the [ARM C Language Extensions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053d/IHI0053D_acle_2_1.pdf).

> Try GCC and  `-march=native`:

As you [may have found](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/ARM-Options.html). GCC for the ARM target separates out `-march` (For the architecture revision for which GCC should generate code), `-mfpu` (For the floating point/Advanced SIMD unit available) and `-mfloat-abi` (For how floating point arguments should be passed, and for the presence or absence of a floating point unit). Finally there is `-mtune` (Which asks GCC to try to optimise for a particular processor) and `-mcpu` (which acts as a combination of `-mtune` and `-march`).

By asking for `-march=native` You're asking GCC to generate code appropriate for the detected architecture of the processor on which you are running. This has no impact on the `-mfpu` setting, and so does not necessarily enable Advanced SIMD instruction generation.

Note that the above only applies to a compiler targeting AArch32. The AArch64 GCC does not support `-mfpu` and will detect presence of Advanced SIMD support through `-march=native`.

> OK, try what Google uses for Android when building for Neon:
>
> `$ g++ -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -dM -E`

These build flags are not sufficient to enable support for Advanced SIMD instructions, your notes may be incomplete. Of the `-mfpu` [flags supported](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/ARM-Options.html) by GCC 4.9.2 I'd expect any of:

`neon`, `neon-fp16`, `neon-vfpv4`, `neon-fp-armv8`, `crypto-neon-fp-armv8`

To give you what you want.

> According to ARM, this board does have Advanced SIMD instructions even though:

Looks like you're running on an AArch64 kernel, which exposes support for Advanced SIMD through the `asimd` feature - as in your example output.

Comment: Thanks James. This should help bridge some of my knowledge gaps.

Comment: Newer gcc no longer defines `__ARM_NEON`.  Older gcc (like 5.4) defines both `__ARM_NEON` and `__ARM_NEON__`.  gcc5.4 and gcc6.3 define `__ARM_FEATURE_SIMD32 1`.  https://godbolt.org/g/LmPjDq Is that what one should check?

Comment: The godbolt compilers you've linked look like they are configured in different ways, (confirmed with -v). You can enable Neon support by adding `-mfloat-abi=hard` to your command line. You might want to report this configuration difference as a bug with the owner of the service. `__ARM_FEATURE_SIMD32` refers to a different part of the instruction set - those that operate on packed 8-bit values in the 32-bit registers, so is not a replacement for `__ARM_NEON`.